# How to make Premiere Pro Connect Hindi Characters?

Tags: premiere, adobe

I am using Premiere Pro CC 2017.

Recently when I try to type "Hindi"  Language via Google Input tools,

Typed text not showing "Joint word" correctly.

But my language working completely at everywhere except Premiere Pro.

**Already Changed text engine to South Asian**

If not understanding my question please visit this question,this problem is for android and my question for Premiere Pro.

Comment: Does the interface mention anything about "Ligatures"? That's the technical term for connecting characters. Perhaps there's a preference to turn it on or off? Also, does it vary if you change the font?

Comment: Yes..there is Ligatures feature.. I turned it on already..

Comment: @user1118321 Problem solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved..

Turned On Ligatures in Preference-Titler

Changed font to Adobe Devnagari

Restarted Premiere

Thanks to @user1118321 for Ligatures Meaning

Comment: Where this ligatures preference is in Windows

Comment: No option to turn on ligature in prefrence -titler it shows only style swatches and font browser thats it